# SQL: British Summer Time in query

Tags: sql-server

I've got this sql query that returns data based on their time and date.

- During the week, it will returns data from 17:00 until 09:00.
- During the weekend, it will returns data from 00:00 until 23:59

The data will match a number value. However, i get data for 8am on 01/06/2017 that was actually 9am.

Is there an easy to make the query to take into account the BST?

```
SELECT 
    I3TimeStampGMT, DNIS, AssignedWorkGroup, LocalName, RemoteNumber, CallDurationSeconds
FROM 
    CIC_Prod.dbo.calldetail_viw 

WHERE
(
    (I3TimeStampGMT > '2017-06-01' 
    AND I3TimeStampGMT <= DATEADD(day,1,'2017-12-01') 
    AND (
        DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) IN (18, 07)
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 17 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 00) 
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 08 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 59)
        )
    AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 2 AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 6
        --sun(1)-mon(2)-tue(3)-wed(4)-thu(5)-fri(6)-sat(7)
        )
    OR I3TimeStampGMT > '2017-06-01' 
    AND I3TimeStampGMT <= DATEADD(day,1,'2017-12-01')
    AND (
        DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) IN (01, 22)
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 00 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 00) 
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 23 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 59)
        )
    AND (DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) = 7 OR DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) = 1)
)
AND
LineId = 'SIP-100-UK'
AND(
DNIS = '4910045'
OR
DNIS = '4910044'
OR
DNIS = '4910043'
OR
DNIS = '4910025'
OR
DNIS = '4910024'
OR
DNIS = '4910023'
OR
DNIS = '4910021'
OR
DNIS = '4910026'
OR
DNIS = '4910019'
OR
DNIS = '4910022'
OR
DNIS = '4910020'
)

order by [I3TimeStampGMT]
```

a sqlfiddle has been created on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afc85a/1

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.calldetail_viw 
    ([I3TimeStampGMT] datetime, [DNIS] nvarchar(50), [AssignedWorkGroup] nvarchar(100), [LocalName] nvarchar(50), [RemoteNumber] nvarchar(50), [CallDurationSeconds] bigint,[LineId] nvarchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO dbo.calldetail_viw 
    ([I3TimeStampGMT], [DNIS], [AssignedWorkGroup], [LocalName], [RemoteNumber], [CallDurationSeconds], [LineId])
VALUES
    ('2017-06-01 07:59:37.863', '4910021',  '-', '%13668%', '+44124578963', '11', 'SIP-100-UK'),
    ('2017-06-01 08:09:37.863', '4910019',  'Test Queue', 'Test User1', '+45325545654', '11', 'SIP-100-UK'),
    ('2017-06-03 15:50:37.863', '4910022',  '-', '%13668%', '+3247852365', '11', 'SIP-100-UK'),
    ('2017-11-08 07:59:37.863', '4910021',  '-', '%13668%', '+44789631545', '11', 'SIP-100-UK'),
    ('2017-11-08 08:09:37.863', '4910019',  '-', '%13668%', '+44458964545', '11', 'SIP-100-UK'),
    ('2017-11-08 10:09:37.863', '4910019',  'Test Queue 2', 'test User2', '+44458964545', '11', 'SIP-100-UK'),
    ('2017-11-25 15:50:37.863', '4910023',  '-', '%13668%', '+44124598723', '11', 'SIP-100-UK')

;
```

result is

```
I3TimeStampGMT              DNIS    AssignedWorkGroup   LocalName   RemoteNumber    CallDurationSeconds
2017-06-01T07:59:37.863Z    4910021     -               %13668%     +44124578963    11
2017-06-01T08:09:37.863Z    4910019     Test Queue      Test User1  +45325545654    11
2017-06-03T15:50:37.863Z    4910022     -               %13668%     +3247852365     11
2017-11-08T07:59:37.863Z    4910021     -               %13668%     +44789631545    11
2017-11-08T08:09:37.863Z    4910019     -               %13668%     +44458964545    11
2017-11-25T15:50:37.863Z    4910023     -               %13668%     +44124598723    11
```

Comment: I assume you're not using the `datetimeoffset` datatype, and using `datetime` or `datetime2`? You'll likely need to create a table which contains details of when Day Light Saving Starts and Stops each year. Then, you can cater for the difference using that. Without any DDL, or sample data, I'm not going to make an attempt at posting a SQL answer.

Comment: please see the sample on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afc85a/1